# Passing Environment Object to dynamic navigation target in SwiftUI NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on writing a Router for my SwiftUI application, and I am having trouble sharing the shared sign up form data between the views.

Here is my Router

```
struct ScanningFlowRouter: Routing {
    func view(for route: ScanningFlowRoute) -> some View {
        var nextView: AnyView
        switch route {
        case .home:
            nextView = AnyView(Landing(startScanningFlow: .constant(false), scanningFlowRouter: self))
        case .name_email:
            nextView = AnyView(NameEmail(scanningFlowRouter: self))
        }
        
        return nextView
    }
}
```

and the `NavigationLink`

```
 NavigationLink(
                destination:
                    scanningFlowRouter.view(for: .name_email),
                isActive: $startScanningFlow,
                label: {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            )
```

The view that is rendering the `NavigationView` and the `NavigationLink` is being passed an environment object via `.environmnetObject(formData: formData)`, however I am getting an error that the `NameEmail` view has no reference to an environment. When I add an environment to my router (editing the env to be a shared singleton) like

```
return nextView.environmentObject(FormData.shared)
```

... my navigation no longer works, and the screen does nothing.

Does anybody know what might be going on?

Comment: AnyView is highly discouraged. Watch “Demystify SwiftUI” there seem to be many points of concern with the snippets you have provided.

Comment: It would be much simpler to have root routing view that simply uses the current route to present the correct view. `AnyView` and functions that return views like this are red flags

Answer (score 1):

I can show some differ navigation style than router (which is not very understandable for me :), it is one of the example how to handle our content.

I prefer to use some basic content manager. For example at your beginning in you can use something like this:

```
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {

   var content: ContentState = .locked

}

extension ContentViewModel {
   enum ContentState {
        // show sign in / registration view
        case locked
        // show tab bar for example
        case unlocked
   }
}
```

And in your content view implement something like this. I like it for environment agility.

```
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
         switch viewModel.screenState {
            case .locked:
                HelloScreenView()
            case .unlocked:
                TabBarView()
        }
    }
}
```

**So somewhere in your logic you can just change your content state, for example after success login**.

And note, that we have there NavigationView from start, so anywhere next put NavigationLinks where you want. Also we can implement similar "manager" for some of our views deeper in our app.

Comment: this is great @Arsienij -- how would you integrate `NagivationLink` into this so I can take advantage of the animation/back functionality, etc?

Comment: @nickhealy for example inside HelloScreenView() you can create 2 navigation links, one for example for sign in and another for registration. That's it about navigation links. In this example we declare navigation view for entire view in our app. That's behaviour will be as usual, you can dismiss your view without problem or do what you want.

If you interest about switching screenState property. So we need to do this somewhere in another place, declaring our state view model and changing property.